# Syntax Error in Datetime range Query in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, datetime

I am executing a ruby query:

```
Timeslot.where("start_date >= ? AND end_date <= ?", Wed, 01 Jul 2015 18:00:00 SGT +08:00, Wed, 01 Jul 2015 21:00:00 SGT +08:00)
```

I am getting the following error

```
 SyntaxError: unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting ')'
...AND end_date <= ?", Wed, 01 Jul 2015 18:00:00 SGT +08:00, We...
```

I suppose it is because I am not escaping the ',' character after Wed. I have two questions:

1) How can I correct this query?
2) I will be replacing  Wed, 01 Jul 2015 18:00:00 SGT +08:00 with an actual datetime variable? How can I type this query in the right way if the datetime were variables and not constants?

Comment: `start_time= Time.now` and `end_time = Time.now + 2.hours`. Query: `Timeslot.where("start_date >= ? AND end_date <= ?", start_time, end_time)`

Comment: `Wed, 01 Jul 2015 18:00:00 SGT +08:00` is neither a valid Ruby date, nor a valid SQL date.

Comment: @Stefan Yes it is. In the default created_at field of rails models, this is the format you are going to find

Comment: Exactly, it's a *format*, i.e. a string representation, not the date itself. Entering `Date.today` in IRB (or rails console) returns a date that is formatted as `Mon, 13 Jul 2015`, but entering `Mon, 13 Jul 2015` results in a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write something like this:

```
Timeslot.where(
  'start_date >= ? AND end_date <= ?', 
  Date.parse('Wed, 01 Jul 2015 18:00:00 SGT +08:00'),
  Date.parse('Wed, 01 Jul 2015 21:00:00 SGT +08:00')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seem that you have to convert string date into in the proper date format to perform query operation. Like you have date in UTC time zone, then its better to use `Time` object and convert into proper date format and use that in your query,

```
str = "Tue, 10 Aug 2010 01:20:19 +0400"
puts Date.parse str
2010-08-10

puts Date.parse(Time.parse(str).utc.to_s)
2010-08-09
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you input parameters Wed, 01 Jul 2015 18:00:00 SGT +08:00 without quotation marks?

I think if you want to use that format. Try this.

```
"Wed, 01 Jul 2015 18:00:00 SGT +08:00".to_time()
# to_time() method converted to Time Class (timezone is followed by rails setting)
```

or

```
"2015-07-01 18:00:00".to_time() # works well.
```

Answer (score 0):

USE [DATETIME](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-parse) ...

```
start_date=DateTime.parse(Wed, 01 Jul 2015 18:00:00 SGT +08:00)
end_date=DateTime.parse(Wed, 01 Jul 2015 21:00:00 SGT +08:00)
Timeslot.where("start_date >= ? AND end_date <= ?",start_date,end_date)
```